# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el hover en un botón para que sea de un color sólido?

Tags: css

Saludos, me gustaría que el botón que dice "suscribete ahora" se quede azul todo el tiempo sin tener que pasar con el cursor sobre el. Actualmente se queda transparente hasta que pases sobre el con el cursor o le des click. Adjunto les envío foto del código y de lo que quiero lograr. Si me pudieran ayudar se los voy a agradecer!

[image: Codigo que quiero modificar]

[image: Muestra de lo que necesito]

Comment: Puedes ver que clase se agrega en el hover con el inspector de elementos de tu navegador y ponerle ese atributo desde un inicio.

Comment: Hola NemeziX, edita tu pregunta y agrega las clases que aplicas a tu botón. Al hacerlo verás que fácil es resolverlo.

Answer (score 1):

Pon la clase, debajo por debajo de donde cargues los estilos de la página para sobreescribirlos:

```
<style>
.sidebar-subscribe-box-email-button {
    background: #2af;
}
</style>
```

o bien modifica el html, poniendole al botón el estilo en línea:

```
<input class="sidebar-subscribe-box-email-button" style="background:#2af" ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funcionó perfectamente tu recomendación.

Comment: @NemeziX, de nada. No te olvides de votar.